# Possible to slide down UITabBarController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitabbarcontroller

I'm sure I've seen code for this somewhere this somewhere, but I can't find it...

I'd like to be able to programatically slide down a UITabBarController... not when transitioning to another view, but within the same view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to slide the `UITabBar` down and up you can try something like:

```
- (IBAction)showHideTabBar:(id)sender {
    static BOOL isShowing = YES;

    CGRect tabBarFrame = self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame;

    if (isShowing) {
        tabBarFrame.origin.y += tabBarFrame.size.height;
    }
    else {
        tabBarFrame.origin.y -= tabBarFrame.size.height;
    }

    isShowing = !isShowing;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^ {
        [self.tabBarController.tabBar setFrame:tabBarFrame];
    }];
}
```

Comment: I think the above solution will leave a blank area the size of the tab bar which cannot be drawn. This may be OS-version-dependant. I am speaking as of iOS 5.1. My current workaround involves moving my view from its controller into the tab bar controller, so that it *can* draw in that bottom area. Not pretty, and would prefer a more elegant solution—-when the view changes controllers, there is a jump in the animation.